# Count values of one column per value of second column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
dummy_dataset = {'sentences': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 'classes': [1,2,1,3,3,2] }
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dummy_dataset)

sentences   classes
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   1
3   d   3
4   e   3
5   f   2
```

What I am looking for is:

```
output = { 1 : ['a','c'], 2 : ['b','f'], 3: ['d','e'] }
```

I tried with dict method :

```
dict_count = {}

for m in range(len(dfg)):
    if dfg['classes'].iloc[m] not in dict_count:
        dict_count[dfg['classes'].iloc[m]] = [dfg['sentences'].iloc[m]]
    else:
        dict_count[dfg['classes'].iloc[m]].append(dfg['sentences'].iloc[m])
```

How can I do this with pandas `count` and `groupby` method?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `classes` column and [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) as list , then [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
dataframe.groupby('classes')['sentences'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

---

Output:

```
{1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b', 'f'], 3: ['d', 'e']}
```